# How to add highlighting of brused points on scatter3 in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, scatter-plot, brush

When I worked with the 2D chart, my points were marked with a red circle around

[image]

After i move to scatter3, and marking points here only changing color to red:

[image]

How to **return the red circle around the point**? It was very convenient

Filled do not works:

[image]

Code:

```
clearvars;
clc;
rng('default');
xsSplited=zeros(1000, 3);
ysSplited=zeros(1000, 3);
zsSplited=zeros(1000, 3);
for i=1:size(xsSplited, 2)
    xsSplited(:, i) = rand(1,1000);
    ysSplited(:, i) = rand(1,1000);
    zsSplited(:, i) = rand(1,1000);
end
distFig=figure(15);
hold on;
colorsOnGrapth={'b.', 'g.', 'k.'};
for i=1:size(xsSplited, 2)
    dalPlot=scatter3(xsSplited(:, i), ysSplited(:, i), zsSplited(:, i), string(colorsOnGrapth(i)));
end
hold off;
```

Answer (score 0):

use the filled argument.

```
scatter3(x,y,z,'filled')
```

Comment: Do not works @Waleed Qaisrani

Comment: can you share your original code?

Comment: yes update queation